# How to statically link libc while keeping dynamic loading?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, libc

I want to build a statically linked application that could use dynamically loadable plugins.
The problem is that I can't get rid of the `libc.so` dependency.

I'm using [`musl libc`](https://www.musl-libc.org/) and compiling like

```
 /opt/cross/x86_64-linux-musl/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-gcc -Wl,-E -fPIC -I... -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -ldl -lc -lgcc source.c -o output_bin foo.a bar.a -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

`readelf -d` shows that executable depends on `libc.so`, so executable doesn't work on other machines without `musl libc`.

Is it possible to include libc symbols into elf executable and link all external plugins to elf itself, without external `.so` dependencies? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try compiling it without the stdlib using `-nostdlib` parameter.